# Verifying that a user is from a certain country

Tags: authentication

I'm helping a small non-profit with their website and we are going to have a login and membership system where we need to verify that a user is from a certain country. How can this be done? (We are going to use Drupal 7 or possibly WordPress if there is a better solution there)

What we have been thinking about so far is using SMS verification when signing up and then checking the country code, but it would need to be cost-free since otherwise a lot of money could be lost for the organization if the verification is done automatically

There's also IP-based verification but this wouldn't help if traffic was bounced

Thoughts, ideas, other suggestions?

Comment: "From": do you mean currently residing or a citizen?

Comment: shroeder: Citizen would be best, but currently residing is also ok

Comment: Most services that do this (YouTube, BBC, etc.) go off the IP address. They mostly accept the risk of traffic being bounced, although known proxies and VPNs are sometimes blacklisted.

Comment: What do you mean by "if traffic was bounced"? Proxied? How accurate does it have to be? What are the consequnces of getting it wrong?

Comment: Reading through your question and the answers elicited so far, I think a crucial question for you and your org is how strong of a need the "need" for limiting users your location area is. What would be the consequences for the non-profit if some (presumably small) proportion of users who had the knowledge & ability to bypass (let's say) a pretty basic regime of ip address location filtering + blacklisting of known proxies *were* able to successfully register as an eligible user?

Comment: symcbean: Yes i was thinking of traffic being proxied or maybe where the ip address was faked in some other way (i'm new at computer security and don't know all the options)

Comment: halinformed: I agree with this line of thinking and i am right now in talks with the founder of the organization (sorry but i can't talk specifics openly). Actually authenticating users in general is important enough that the whole approach that the organization takes may be changed depending on what options we have. Therefore i am grateful for the range of answers to this question and this discussion which helps make things more clear when thinking about it and discussing it with the founder

Comment: To put it another way, when it comes to verifying a user's location over the Internet for purposes of determining whether a user can access a service, there's a big difference between situations where an organization can say "I need to be seen as making a reasonable effort to restrict use by location, but if a few users behind proxies make it through here and there it's not a huge deal." and "I need to limit access to people from this geography as best as humanly possible, because for each case where that might fail the consequences could be serious."

Comment: Ah, you replied before I posted the second comment. :)

Comment: If authenticating users in general is that important, then I'm imagine you might have little choice but to go with something like a credit/debit card identity verification service (there are some that are free to use for the org, and only charge the user a dollar or two, I think). If you want something free to the user, an address verification mailer with a code in it for a user to enter in the site might be a serviceable option. (Neither of those are ideal options or completely foolproof controls, of course.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that you are going to find a free and effective way to do this that doesn't expose your users to privacy issues.

For instance, I just moved to a new country. I have a phone, drivers licenses, accounts, and IDs in both countries. I sign up for services limited to residents of these countries. There is no way for any of these services to know for sure where I really am.

One way to increase the assurance is to get copies of your users' national documents: birth certificates, national ID cards. But then you will have to deal with the fact that you have these sensitive documents and the privacy issues they expose.

At best, you will be able to determine that someone was able to sign up for services in a particular country, and that's it. You will have to decide if that's enough for your organisation.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has a free SMS-based authentication service called [Digits](https://get.digits.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do that. You will have to determine based on your environment, speed and other considerations what works best for you.

- You can use something like the script from [phptutorial](http://www.phptutorial.info/iptocountry/the_script.html) which allows you to determine the ipaddress of visitors and take an action
- Since you mentioned that you could be using drupal, you can rework [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/geoblocker) which tries to whitelist or blacklist users based on their location.
- The module actually used the Geolocation information based on [Php Geoip functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) so could use them to determine it.
- Finally you can always search for [ip to country](https://www.google.com/search?q=ip%20to%20country.inc&oq=ip%20to%20country.inc) which can provide you some commercial solutions as well.

I would suggest understanding the actual reasoning behind why they want this functionality. Look at their Google Analytics reports to check if they even get any users from bunch of other countries. Also maybe if they care about only certain countries than either whitelist or blacklist approaches may help as well. So ensure to dig deeper and learn "why" they actually want this feature to be able to develop a time and cost feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only elegant solution I'd be able to identify to help with this would be to use a ***location-aware*** two-factor authentication product that is like Duo Security's Platform Edition for two-factor authentication.

Since the Duo app essentially acts like mobile device management (MDM), it has the ability to use GPS in addition to the traditional IP location based on databases and assignments at the ISP level, e.g. what YouTube etc uses.   There may be other MDM software that does this, but Duo is the only one I'm aware of in wide use.

Their model allows you to whitelist certain countries for login, but disallow other countries by policy.  It also keeps records with the country location of each logins so you can run said logs through anomaly detection (or manual review) to see if there are unusual login locations.

Here's links to their site detailing their implementation:

https://duo.com/solutions/features/endpoint-visibility/policies-and-controls
https://duo.com/solutions/features/policy-and-controls/geolocation

However, this tool is geared towards a corporate environment and costs a monthly subscription fee -- for doing this on the web for open enrollment, there is nothing comparable.

Most apps and services that filter based on IP origin depend on third party geolocation or "fraud detection" services that use IP reputation management tools (e.g. is this IP a VPN endpoint or proxy? known compromised machine?), along with IP-based geolocation to determine if traffic should be allowed or not.